# Is there a way for a Zen Archer to enchant arrows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranged-attack

Is there a feat to let a Zen Archer use his Ki to enchant an arrow to have the same property as Monk Ki strike of the same level?

If not is there a class a Zen Archer can multiclass into to be able to enchant his arrows?

Answer (score 4):

### Greater Magic Weapon

The feat you are asking for is already built into the Zen Archer as a class feature at level 17

> ##### Ki Focus Bow (Su)
>
> At 17th level, as long as he has at least 1 point of ki in his ki pool, a zen archer may treat arrows fired from his bow as if they were ki focus weapons, **allowing him to use his special ki attacks as if his arrows were unarmed attacks**.

So, from 17th level on, any Zen Archer can use his arrows as if they were unarmed attacks as for his ki strikes. I did not find a feat that accelerates this, and I doubt there is one -- it would be strange to provide a built-in class level feature as a feat to shortcut it.

If you don't want to wait until 17th level, any class that allows you to cast [Greater Magic Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/) allows you to enchant your arrows.

> Alternatively, you can affect as many as 50 arrows, bolts, or bullets.

The following classes have access to this spell, which means it would at least take a 5-level "dip"

> antipaladin 3, bloodrager 3, cleric/oracle 4, inquisitor 3, magus 3, paladin 3, shaman 4, sorcerer/wizard 3